# UV unwrapping seems to be unwrapping my object twice

Tags: uv

Following the anvil series meticulously for the second time now and I have a new and weird problem. When I UV unwrap, not UV smart unwrap, I get what seems to be 2 unwraps! So when I create a seam and re unwrap, the UV editor displays this double unwrapping. I don't know how else to explain this. Here is an image to help explain.

[image]

I tried using an older version of blender to see if there was a difference. It's so weird because yesterday it was working fine for me, but when I cmd+z back a couple of times it erased everything, and so I figured that I would quit for the day. Now it's doing this crazy result! See how in the bottom left there is this additional UV map that I don't want. It's driving me absolutely crazy. Why is it seem to be unwrapping it twice? 
See how it's got 2 UV unwraps? Thank you for any help.[image] See how it's creating this terrible triangle situation when I render it. Also, it doesn't show me any texturing in texture mode *(image missing)*

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you accidentally duplicated parts of your mesh.
In this case you have to merge the vertices that are on the same location.
The easiest way to do this is to use the Remove Doubles operator:
*Select All (A-key) > Press W-Key for Specials Menu > Remove Doubles*
After removing the duplicate vertices you have to unwrap the mesh again.